# shapefile bounding box not set correctly via rest api geoserver

Tags: c#, geoserver

Hi According to this  [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27447/upload-shapefile-using-geoserver-rest-api-and-c?rq=1)  i write methods to Add Store and ShapeFile to Geoserver , that work correctly but when get preview of layer said  bbox is incorrect

> illegal bbox, minX: 0.0 is greater than maxX: -1.0

after add shapefile when i change manually from geoserver web interface its work properly but i i wanna programmatically
this is my code

```
 public bool UploadShapeFile()
    {

        var uploads = Path.Combine(_host.WebRootPath, "Upload");
        var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, "states_25.zip");
        string result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        String fileUri = filePath;
        Console.Write(fileUri);

        byte[] localShapeFile = readLocalShapeFile(fileUri);

        String sUrl = "http://192.168.1.2:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces" +
            "/sf/datastores/sf3/file.shp";

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(sUrl);

        request.ContentType = "application/zip";
        request.Method = "PUT";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "geoserver");

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(localShapeFile, 0, localShapeFile.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        CreatePostGISTableAndFeatureType();
        return true;
    }

    public bool CreatePostGISTableAndFeatureType()
    {
        string featXml = GetXml();
        string fUrl =   "http://192.168.1.2:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces" +
            "/sf/datastores/sf3/featuretypes";

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(fUrl);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "geoserver");

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(featXml);

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {

        }


        return false;
    }
    private string GetXml()
    {
        string fXml = "<featureType>" +
                        "<name>sepp</name>" +
                        "<nativeName>sepp</nativeName>" +
                        "<title>sepp</title>" +
                        "<srs>EPSG:4326</srs>" +
                        "<attributes>" +
                            "<attribute>" +
                                "<name>the_geom</name>" +
                                "<binding>com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point</binding>" +
                            "</attribute>" +
                            "<attribute>" +
                                "<name>description</name>" +
                                "<binding>java.lang.String</binding>" +
                            "</attribute>" +
                            "<attribute>" +
                                "<name>timestamp</name>" +
                                "<binding>java.util.Date</binding>" +
                            "</attribute>" +
                        "</attributes>" +
                    "</featureType>";
        return fXml;
    }

    private byte[] readLocalShapeFile(string filePath)
    {
        byte[] buffer;
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        try
        {
            int length = (int)fStream.Length;
            buffer = new byte[length];
            int count;
            int sum = 0;

            while ((count = fStream.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
                sum += count;
        }
        finally
        {
            fStream.Close();
        }

        return buffer;
    }
```

Thank you so much in advance for your attention

Answer (score 0):

You need to either specify the bounding box of your data set in the XML file you `PUT` to the server or include the `recalculate` option to the request.

See the [REST Manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#1.0.0/featuretypes.yaml) for full details:

> recalculate array string
>
> Specifies whether to recalculate any bounding boxes for a feature type. Some properties of feature types are automatically recalculated when necessary. In particular, the native bounding box is recalculated when the projection or projection policy are changed, and the lat/lon bounding box is recalculated when the native bounding box is recalculated, or when a new native bounding box is explicitly provided in the request. (The native and lat/lon bounding boxes are not automatically recalculated when they are explicitly included in the request.) In addition, the client may explicitly request a fixed set of fields to calculate, by including a comma-separated list of their names in the recalculate parameter. The empty parameter ‘recalculate=’ is useful avoid slow recalculation when operating against large datasets as ‘recalculate=’ avoids calculating any fields, regardless of any changes to projection, projection policy, etc. The nativebbox parameter ‘recalculate=nativebbox’ is used recalculates the native bounding box, while avoiding recalculating the lat/lon bounding box. Recalculate parameters can be used in together - ‘recalculate=nativebbox,latlonbbox’ can be used after a bulk import to to recalculates both the native bounding box and the lat/lon bounding box.